# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I created a Database First Entity Data Model under a WPF Project. I then added a DataGrid and Binded it to the model. I've been trying to add CRUD capability.

All was good until I added a Button and tied its click event to save the updated data. Once I clicked on this I'd get the following runtime error.

> ```
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
> ```

So I checked the inner exception and got the following:

> ```
> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.&mdash;> System.NotSupportedException: Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'Symbol_and_BenchmarkID'. Table: 'BenchMarkModel.Store.Weights'.
> ```

Where is `StoreGeneratePattern` so I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Its located in the .edmx file. Search for the StoreGeneratePattern in that file.

When you create an ADO model through visual studio's code creation buttons, the code that is generated is done so with a few assumptions. In this case the its your computed column thats causing the problem.

This was a very specific issue that I was able to solve and wanted to give back. Edits welcome!